# How to make a Window-like background in XML for Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on an app that requires me to create a Window-like background in Android like

[image: this],

where each pane represents an `Image` that can be pressed.

**I have come up with**

[image: this],

but I don't know how to set the grids. I have used `TableLayout` here & I want each of my `TableRows` to have such a background that it looks like it's forming the grid of the Window.

Following is the background created in XML that is used by my `TableLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#FDFDFD"/>
    <stroke android:color="#454545" android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

try to use gridview.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a GridView or a RecyclerView with gridlayoutmanager to get a proper scrollable grid-like arrangement.

Use a GridView if you want the coding to be nice and easy; however it will need a viewholder pattern for smooth scrolling. If you want super flexibility like directions of scrolling etc. Use a RecyclerView if you need to use a viewholder pattern anyway.

RecyclerView supports Grids, Linear and StaggeredGrids with horizontal and/or vertical scrolling. It uses a LayoutManager to handle all this -> LinearLayoutManager, GridLayoutManager StaggeredGridLayoutManager with direction either horizontal or vertical.

---

Reference for GridView: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Reference for RecyclerView: https://realm.io/news/android-recycler-view/

Comment: i suggest you use gridview if you want the coding to be nice and easy however it will need a viewholder pattern for smooth scrolling. Although if you want super flexibility like directions of scrolling etc.. use recycler view and it will anyway make you use a viewholder pattern.

Comment: Will the `RecyclerView` have grids?

Comment: RecyclerView supports Grids, Linear and StaggeredGrids all in both horizontal and vertical scrolling

Comment: It uses a LayoutManager to handle all this -> LinearLayoutManager, GridLayoutManager StaggeredGridLayoutManager with direction either horizontal or vertical. It is a tad bit difficult to manage a recyclerview compared to grid or listview though. Read thoroughly before attempting it :)